# XmlValidate in ant with namespace

Tags: ant, xml-validation

How can i validate these xml and xsd  file with xmlvalidate task with Ant . i have tried but didn't get solution for it .can i get a solution

```
<property name="doc.xsd" location="${basedir}/test.xsd" />

<target name="FindDesc" >
   <xmlvalidate file="ab.xml" lenient="yes" failonerror="yes" warn="yes">
          <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="ab.xsl" />
            <attribute name="http://xml.org/sax/features/validation" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema"  value="true"/>
            <attribute name="http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces" value="true"/>
          <property name="http://apache.org/xml/properties/schema/external-noNamespaceSchemaLocation" value="${doc.xsd}" />
      </xmlvalidate>


  </target>
```

ab.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books xmlns="http://www.example.org/Test" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd">
   <book id="bk001">
      <author>Writer</author>   
      <title>The First Book</title>
      <genre>Fiction</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <pub_date>2000-10-01</pub_date>
      <review>An amazing story of nothing.</review>
   </book>

   <book id="bk002">
      <author>Poet</author>
      <title>The Poet's First Poem</title>
      <genre>Poem</genre>
      <price>24.95</price>
      <review>Least poetic poems.</review>
   </book>
</books>
```

test.xsd

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"  targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Test"
           >

  <xsd:element name="books" >

   <xsd:complexType >
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="book" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
     <xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="author"   type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="title"    type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="genre"    type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="price"    type="xsd:float" />
      <xsd:element name="pub_date" type="xsd:date" />
      <xsd:element name="review"   type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id"   type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

i have tried to test xml with xsd schema with Ant Script  i get its not working as mine  i get error like this

```
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'books'.
```

and with these

```
TargetNamespace.2: Expecting no namespace, but the schema document has a target namespace of 'http://www.example.org/Test'.
```

xml with no namespace but i want to try to validate with namespace through ant script ..
what can i do if there is any error please give suggestion to test these xml and xsd file with ant script i have gone through xml validation and schema validation

Answer (score 0):

we can use SchemaValidation its easy and fast way to validate the xml with xsd file

If there is one file we can go through this

```
  <schemavalidate>
<schema namespace="<schema_nameSpace>">
        file="abc.xml"/>
   </schemavalidate>
```

If multiple file is there we can use fileset

```
<schemavalidate warn="true" failonerror="true" fullchecking="true">
        <fileset dir="<Src_dir_for_Xml>">
            <include name="*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <schema namespace="<Your schema name space>" file="<schema_src_dir_For_schema" />
    </schemavalidate>
```